# How to get the peak value of a second order system that has non-zero initial condition with step input?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory, linear-control

It is known that the **peak value of a second order system** which is excited with a **step input** can be expressed by

$y(t_p)=1+e^{({-\pi\zeta}/{\sqrt{1-\zeta^2}})}$

In my case, the **initial conditions are non-zero**. I've solved the differential equation, took its first derivative and then set it to zero, thus got the peak value. But this requires **lots of computation time**.

Is there a way similar to the one above for non-zero initial conditions case?

Comment: Can you write down exactly what equation has the property you described? Also, can you write down your problem?

Comment: $y''(t)+py'(t)+qy(t)=r$; where $y'(0)=y_0$; $y(0)=0$; p, q, r are constants. Let's say a step input is applied setting $r=1$

Comment: Does $\zeta$ refer to the damping constant? Such that $y''+2\zeta\omega_0y'+\omega_0^2y$?

Comment: yes that is right.